# How can I get the last inserted primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2005 with a table with a primary key field with the type `varchar(40)`. I have to get the last inserted record's primary key value. I have tried `scope_identity` but it is not working. How can I get this?

Comment: How is the primary key values being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the result.

Code:

```
insert into T
output inserted.pk
values ('new item');
```

Comment: This should work for you. Scope_identity only works with identity key.

Answer (score 1):

If your ID is a varchar I suppose it's not auto generated so you should know it before you insert a record . BTW can't you just select your id after you insert a record?
Something like this:

```
CREATE PROC InsertXXX( ... value parameters...)
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT .....
SELECT ID FROM MyTable
END
```

**UPDATED :**

If you want to know the last inserted record and its ID before inserting a new record it can be a little bit harder depending on ID values.

If you can find the last record by sorting ID column you can do it as follows:

```
SELECT Max(ID) FROM myTable
```

If not you can have a DateTime filed (CreationDate for example) that holds the time of insertion of the record.Then you can do as follows:

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE CreationDate=(SELECT Max(CreationDate) FROM MyTable)
```