# Getting the last inserted rows primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How may I get the last inserted row's primary key?

P.S Note that the primary key is of type `VARCHAR` so `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesn't work for me..

I found this question: [How can I get the last inserted primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419606/how-can-i-get-the-last-inserted-primary-key?rq=1) but I wasn't able to understand what he is saying

> insert into T
>   output inserted.pk
>   values ('new item');

Can anyone please guide me with this, as I am new to SQL Server and wasn't able to understand the point here?

Thanks.

Comment: OUTPUT Inserted.Pk will give you the id which is get generated once you run the insert query, if you want to get the id of last inserted record(before run the insert query) then you may use 'max()'. i.e. SELECT max([id]) FROM [TableName]. what is your real requirement here?

Comment: If the primary key is of type `varchar` then some custom code is generating it - this is either your own code immediately before the `INSERT` or, say, a trigger. But in both cases, it is custom code - so you shouldn't expect SQL Server to be able to magically tell you what this code did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a table variable for example:

```
declare @newIds table(id nvarchar(255));
```

And then insert into that table output of inserted items like this:

```
insert into DestinationTable(col1,col2)
   output inserted.Key into newIds 
select
   col1,col2
from
   SourceTable
```

[Key] is supposed to be the name of your PrimaryKey column.

After this all new Keys will be in @newIds table.